# S3 video and Chewei loading videos too slow

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3

Hi I am using s3 to upload videos. And chewie for playing the video in flutter. Now the problem is the video playback is too slow ie. it initially loads up very slow and buffers too much. While if I upload the video to youtube and play it in youtube flutter plugin then the same video plays without any buffering and loads up quickly.
Is it due to s3 or my chewei settings are wrong

```
class CheweiList extends StatefulWidget {
String link;
CheweiList(this.link);
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
 return _CheweiList(link);
 } 
 }

 class _CheweiList extends State<CheweiList> {
 String link;
  VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
 ChewieController _chewieController;
  Future _future;
 _CheweiList(this.link);
 Future initVideoPlayer() async {
   await videoPlayerController.initialize();
   setState(() {
     _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
      //aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      autoInitialize: true,
      looping: false,
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(child: Text(errorMessage));
        });
    });
 }

  @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
       videoPlayerController = 
     VideoPlayerController.network(link);
      _future = initVideoPlayer();
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
     child: Container(
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return Center(
            child: videoPlayerController.value.initialized
                ? AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                    child: Chewie(
                      controller: _chewieController,
                    ),
                  )
                : CircularProgressIndicator());
       },
       ),
       ),
     );
  }

   @override
  void dispose() {
   super.dispose();
   videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
 }
 }
```

If it's due to s3 then what is the best process to play a video through s3?
And if it's because of video player then what can I do?

Comment: did you found any fix

Comment: I have changed my links to play from amazon cloud front. This solves the problem.

Comment: We did the change to `CloudFront` and we still have this problem.

Comment: did you use the changed urls given by cloud front ( replace https://s3.xyz with new cloud front url)

Comment: I did, yes, but it had this delay at loading network videos.